# WGAN with simplest data

Tags: pytorch, gan

I want to train WGAN (pyTorch) to generate this simple data.

[image]

Here below my generator and critic architechtures:

```
discriminator = nn.Sequential(
nn.Linear(2, 8),
nn.Linear(8, 1)
)
discriminator = nn.Sequential(
nn.Linear(2, 8),
nn.Linear(8, 1)
)
```

Here training loop:

```
epochs = 10
opt_d = torch.optim.RMSprop(discriminator.parameters(), lr=0.00005)
opt_g = torch.optim.RMSprop(generator.parameters(), lr=0.00005)
discriminator.train()
generator.train()
for epoch in np.arange(epochs):
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch}, ', end='')
    for real_data, real_target in dl:
        for i in range(10):
        # critic train
            opt_d.zero_grad()
            real_pred = discriminator(real_data)        
            fake_pred = discriminator(generator(torch.rand(batch_size, 2)))
            loss_dis = -torch.mean(real_pred + fake_pred)
            loss_dis.backward()
            opt_d.step()
        
            for p in discriminator.parameters():
                p.data.clamp(-0.01, 0.01)
    
    # generator train
    opt_g.zero_grad()
    fake_pred = discriminator(generator(torch.rand(batch_size, 2)))
    
    loss_gen = -torch.mean(fake_pred)
    loss_gen.backward()
    opt_g.step()
```

Here is result:

[image]

Increasing number of layers doesn't help. Where is the error?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the number of epochs? Training the WGAN for only 10 epochs seems quite short. In addition, increasing the learning rate might help.

Comment: The result of 500 epochs and lr=0.0005 almost the same (including intermediate result after 100/150/... epochs)